# Split array into two even sets of integers, each so that both sets add up to the same number

Tags: java, arrays, knapsack-problem, partition-problem

I have had this problem for an interview and can't seem to wrap my mind around how to solve it. I have not found any tutorials that explains the logic behind it as well.

Have the function `ArrayChallenge(arr)`, take the array of integers stored in `arr` which will always contain an even amount of integers, and determine how they can be split into two even sets, then return a string representation of the first set followed by the second set with each integer separated by a comma and both sets sorted in ascending order. The set that goes first is the set with smallest first integer.

For example if arr is [16,22,35,8,20,1,21,11], then your program should output 1,11,20,35,8,16,21,22

[16,22,35,8,20,1,21,11] sum = 134

the sum of 1,11,20,35 is = 67
the sum of 8,16,21,22 is = 67

Also the size of the two arrays are equal to arr.length /2

Comment: Sort the array anyway. Most array problems you generally need to sort. When sorted the first and last elements are in the one list while the second and second last ones are in the other list. The 4 middle numbers are confusing me tho as when writing it out I thought it was all even placed nums in one list and all odd placed nums in another, but that is not right tho

Answer (score 2):

The problem need not to be sequentially-in-time coded. Make a centrally procedure to solve this knapsack problem, but do not code it yet. Then sort the results, and give the results.

Now should you fail solving, say for time-out, there still is an approach done.

The problem could be further simplified, by using the sum of the array `arr`, divide it by 2, and search a subarray of this half-sum.

The problem poses some weird restrictions: `arr` keeps an even number of values (8), the two resulting arrays should have the same even number of values (both 4).

To select to which subarray the i<sup>th</sup> value belongs is binary.

So start with a sorted array, cut the solutions when the half is reached.

You could start with 00001111 (half the bits 1) which probably is too big, the following bits would be 00010111, 00011011, 00011101, 00011110, 00101110, ...

Easier would probably simple recursion, with a count upto the half:

```
// Array arr sorted decreasingly to have less values to try out.
boolean solve(Set<Integer> selectedNumbers, int selectedSum, int index) {
    if (selectedNumbers.size() >= arr.length/2) {
        return sum == arrSum/2;
    }
    if (index > arr.length) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean solved = false;

    // First case: add array element at this index:
    if (selectedSum + arr[index] <= arrSum/2) {
        seplectedNumbers.add(arr[index]);
        arrSum += arr[index];
        solved = solve(selectedNumbers, arrSum, index + 1);
        if (!solved) {
            // No remove(int index), so remove an Object, Integer.
            selectedNumbers.remove(Integer.valueOf(arr[index]));
            arrSum -= arr[index];
        }
    }

    // Second case: do not add array element at this index:
    if (!solved) {
        solved = solve(selectedNumbers, arrSum, index + 1);
    }
    return solved;
}
```

The above of course is a brute force solution. If you are into Operations Research you might find a distribution of those numbers to start with (like the bits mentioned). But time needed and for me my meager math knowledge would prevent that.
When solved you might put in a remark should you know a faster solution.

Comment: Another improvement would be to check whether `discardedSum > arrSum/2` (to be incremented in the second-case branch), since you can go wrong both ways - if you discard too high a total, you will not find equilibrium down that path. Otherwise, I doubt that this can be much improved on.

Comment: @tucuxi as reviewer I would pay attention to things like `do; recurse; undo` and pitfalls like `remove(int)`. But `discardedSum > ...` to cut is very fine. My code does not _look_ fine too.

Comment: I meant algorithmically. Yes, your code is messy and does not compile - but you knew that already :-)

Comment: @tucuxi I am certain this is not the case here, but I have encountered a couple of work-by-googling folks, so I surely will not put effort for too elegant code. Would have been delighted seeing your answer though. An other time.

Comment: I took the time to write an answer - and avoided inserting-and-removing to (my equivalent of) `selectedNumbers`, which should speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar in spirit to that of [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69615198/15472). It implements the (smallish) optimization of checking both `selectedTotal` *and* `discardedTotal` to abort a branch if it exceeds the goal (note that this assumes that all values are positive; if this is not the case, and the smallest value is, say, `x < 0`, you would just have to add `-x` to all values, run the algorithm, and substract `-x` from the answers).

The output is exactly as specified by the original post - and since it is only generated when a full solution is found, this code *should* be faster than algorithms where values are being constantly added and removed from a partial answer, such as Joop's (`selectedNumbers.add` followed by `selectedNumbers.remove` when it turns out not to work; set operations may be fast, but not performing them is even faster!).

```
public class Main {
    public static boolean search(int[] values, int goal, int index,
                                int selectedTotal, int discardedTotal,
                                List<Integer> selected, List<Integer> discarded) {
        if (selected.size() == values.length/2 &&
                discarded.size() == values.length/2) {
            return selectedTotal == goal;
        }
        if (selectedTotal > goal ||
                discardedTotal > goal ||
                index == values.length) {
            return selectedTotal == goal;
        }

        // try selecting value at index ...
        if (selected.size() < values.length/2 &&
                search(values, goal, index + 1,
                    selectedTotal + values[index], discardedTotal,
                    selected, discarded)) {
            selected.add(values[index]);
            return true;
        }

        // ... and, if that did not work, try discarding value at index
        if (discarded.size() < values.length/2 &&
                search(values, goal, index + 1,
                    selectedTotal, discardedTotal + values[index],
                    selected, discarded)) {
            discarded.add(values[index]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static List<Integer> solve(int[] values) {
        Arrays.sort(values);
        int goal = IntStream.of(values).sum() / 2;
        List<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> discarded = new ArrayList<>();
        if ( ! search(values, goal, 0,
                0, 0, selected, discarded)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This puzzle cannot be solved");
        }
        Collections.reverse(selected);
        Collections.reverse(discarded);
        selected.addAll(discarded);
        return selected;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(new int[] {16,22,35,8,20,1,21,11}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution works to find two sub arrays with equal sum. But the two subarrays are not the size of half of the array given.    the array has to be divided into two equal subarrays where each subarray is = to arr.lenght/2;

Answer (score 0):

you would use an iteration and traverse the array first. then you make 2 integers.
In each iteration cycle, you first check if integer1 is bigger than integer2. then put one number in array1 and add its value to integer1. repeat.
if int1 is bigger than int2, you put it in array2 and add the value to int2.
in the end, sort the array and you are done.
that is how I would solve it. Does this work? I am genuinely interested.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [16, 22, 35, 8, 20, 1, 21, 11];

function accumulate(arr, first, last) {
  let init = 0;
  for (let i = first; i < last; i++) {
    init = init + arr[i];
  }
  return init;
}


function combinationUtil(arr, half, start, end,
  index, n, sum) {

  // Current combination is ready to
  // be printed, print it
  if (index == n / 2) {
    let curr_sum = accumulate(half, 0, n / 2);
    return (curr_sum + curr_sum == sum);
  }

  // Replace index with all possible elements.
  // The condition "end-i+1 >= n/2-index" makes
  // sure that including one element at index
  // will make a combination with remaining
  // elements at remaining positions
  for (let i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= n / 2 - index; i++) {
    half[index] = arr[i];
    if (combinationUtil(arr, half, i + 1, end,
        index + 1, n, sum))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function evenSlpit(arr) {
  const n = arr.length;
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const sum = arr.reduce((acc, red) => acc + red, 0);

  if (n % 2 != 0)
    return false;

  // If sum of array is not even.
  if (sum % 2 != 0)
    return false;

  // A temporary array to store all
  // combination one by one let k=n/2;
  let half = [];

  // Print all combination using temporary
  // array 'half[]'
  const res = combinationUtil(arr, half, 0, n - 1,
    0, n, sum);
  if (res) {
    const temp = [...half];
    const otherHalf = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (temp.includes(arr[i])) {
        const index = temp.indexOf(arr[i]);
        temp.splice(1, index);
      } else {
        otherHalf.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return [...half.sort((a, b) => a - b), ...otherHalf.sort((a, b) => a - b)]
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(evenSlpit(arr))
console.log(evenSlpit([1,2,3,4]))
console.log(evenSlpit([1,7,8,3,5,4]));
```